# Has Twitter elaborated on continuing to allow Trump to use the platform for reportedly hateful attacks

Tags: donald-trump, social-media, hate-speech

It seems clear that Trump is using Twitter as a venue to attack some people.

> Trump steps up attack on 'US-hating' congresswomen
>
> US President Donald Trump has redoubled his attack on four Democratic congresswomen, accusing them of "hating our country".
>
> He was widely accused of racism and xenophobia, which he denied.

[Source BBC News](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-48997008)

The Twitter policy on "Hateful conduct policy"

> Hateful conduct: You may not promote violence against or directly attack or threaten other people on the basis of race, ethnicity, national origin, sexual orientation, gender, gender identity, religious affiliation, age, disability, or serious disease. We also do not allow accounts whose primary purpose is inciting harm towards others on the basis of these categories.
>
> We recognise that if people experience abuse on Twitter, it can jeopardize their ability to express themselves. Research has shown that some groups of people are disproportionately targeted with abuse online. This includes; women, people of color, lesbian, gay, bisexual, transgender, queer, intersex, asexual individuals, marginalized and historically underrepresented communities. For those who identity with multiple underrepresented groups, abuse may be more common, more severe in nature and have a higher impact on those targeted.
>
> We are committed to combating abuse motivated by hatred, prejudice or intolerance, particularly abuse that seeks to silence the voices of those who have been historically marginalized. For this reason, we prohibit behavior that targets individuals with abuse based on protected category.

How is it that his Twitter account remains an active vehicle of attack, where it would seem to be prohibited by Twitter policy?

Comment: I don't see how this is not a question on twitter's terms and services, and interpretation of them rather than politics

Comment: @Orangesandlemons It is a political question because it assumes the answer is "because he is the president" however given no one is going to come out and say that, any answer is going to be opinion based.

Comment: @Jonita, even if that's the case, I don't see how it's politics in terms of this site, unless we want to define every platforms t and c enforcement as politics. (And of course why custom service is better for them etc. Etc.

Comment: @Jontia except it's not because Twitter has made statements addressing this, not just for Trump but in general. As such, it's not opinion-based.

Comment: @JJJ Ultimately this comes down to "Do Trump's tweets violate the Twitter T&Cs" Yes/No will be opinion based.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons I don't see how Twitter is that much different from other media as it comes to being on or off topic on this site. The reason some (not all media would be on-topic here either) are is because they are politically relevant. In this case because Trump, but also many other politicians, use the platform in a way that it's a point of discussion **in politics**.

Comment: @Jontia no, because Twitter (per their tweets in my answer) responded to reports about Trump's tweets. It doesn't go into whether they violate the T&Cs but it does say regardless of that that it won't remove tweets if they consider them to be sufficiently newsworthy. My answer is very dated and Bobson's isn't that specific either. I think there's a better answer out there (based on statements by Twitter) without having to go into any specific Trump tweet and how it fares with the T&Cs.

Answer (score 4):

Bobson is right, but it's not that new. In 2017 there was a [tweet](https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/911789314169823232) which some (North Korea) interpreted as a ["clear declaration of war"](https://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2017/09/25/553475174/declaration-of-war-means-north-korea-can-shoot-down-u-s-bombers-minister-says). According to [NPR](https://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2017/09/25/553475174/declaration-of-war-means-north-korea-can-shoot-down-u-s-bombers-minister-says):

> North Korea's foreign minister says President Trump's tweets about the Korean nation amount to a declaration of war and that under international law, his country can legally shoot down U.S. military planes — even if they're not in North Korea's airspace.

Twitter's @Policy account [tweeted](https://twitter.com/Policy/status/912438520429662208) in response to that NPR article:

> THREAD: Some of you have been asking why we haven't taken down the Tweet mentioned here: http://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2017/09/25/553475174/declaration-of-war-means-north-korea-can-shoot-down-u-s-bombers-minister-says … 1/6
>
> We hold all accounts to the same Rules, and consider a number of factors when assessing whether Tweets violate our Rules 2/6
>
> Among the considerations is "newsworthiness" and whether a Tweet is of public interest 3/6
>
> This has long been internal policy and we'll soon update our public-facing rules to reflect it. We need to do better on this, and will 4/6
>
> Twitter is committed to transparency and keeping people informed about what's happening in the world 5/6
>
> We’ll continue to be guided by these fundamental principles 6/6

Comment: So, basically, this was always their policy, but they've finally actually updated their terms to explicitly permit it, rather than arbitrarily just choosing not to apply them.

Comment: @Bobson I guess they started the policy some time before, possibly years before Trump ran for president. Obviously, his position as a presidential candidate and now as president means Twitter is much more under fire about how to deal with this. And as you see here too, there's always many edge cases and it's hard to be consistent. By doing it this way, they can always claim *newsworthiness* and avoid making decisions.

Comment: I can't see why this answer is getting so many downvotes. It seems insightful to me regarding Twitter policy, even though not being precisely about the event the OP asked about..

Answer (score 1):

Twitter specifically changed their policy to answer this question.

[Here is the relevant blog post](https://blog.twitter.com/en_us/topics/company/2019/publicinterest.html)

> With this in mind, there are certain cases where it may be in the public’s interest to have access to certain Tweets, even if they would otherwise be in violation of our rules. On the rare occasions when this happens, we'll place a notice – a screen you have to click or tap through before you see the Tweet – to provide additional context and clarity. We’ll also take steps to make sure the Tweet is not algorithmically elevated on our service, to strike the right balance between enabling free expression, fostering accountability, and reducing the potential harm caused by these Tweets.

Comment: Downvoters, care to comment?

Comment: While I haven't downvoted it might be because the tweets in question are not behind a click through screen. Rendering the reference to a not applied policy moot.

Comment: @Bobson, I did, but to further explain my reasoning - I strongly believe that the question is as off topic as 'why did a sausage firm do a photo op with Boris Johnson' and that by necessity the answer is also so. Nothing personal.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons - I said this before, but my comment got cleaned up with the rest, so I'll repeat it: I don't necessarily agree with "downvote answers to bad/off topic questions", but I can understand it.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Bobson fair enough. Also might be worth me adding that my own logic (right or wrong) would only apply to off-topic questions

Comment: Did Twitter actually apply that warning screen to any of Trump's tweets?